# Fundamental group of 2-Tori

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It is well-known that $\pi_1(T\sharp T) = \langle x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2 \mid x_iy_ix_i^{-1}y_i^{-1}\rangle$.

2-Tori has two holes and consider taking a loop between those two holes. (Between two holes locally resembles a cylinder, so I am just taking a loop around the cylinder). This is clearly a loop, and the question is, what is the expression of this loop? Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Sure. I’ll try with your comment in mind.

Comment: Your presentation is incorrect, it should be the **product** of two commutators. Incidentally, this surface is not called "2-torus" but the "genus 2 surface."